# How can I change some text to lowercase and replace spaces with hyphens using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, input

I have a hidden input field that will take the value of another on keyup and I'm trying to figure out how transform the value in the hidden field to lowercase and replace spaces with hyphens.

So, if someone types "This Is A Sample" in the title input field, the identifier input field will be set to "this-is-a-sample".

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="This Is A Sample" />
<input type="hidden" name="identifier" value="this-is-a-sample />
```

Comment: if this is being used as a way to generate a url segment, you may want to expand the requirements so that it replaces, strips out, or encodes problematic characters as well (#, /, <, >, etc.).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This will replace all spaces with -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var test= $('input[name="title"]').val();
test = test.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');
$('input[name="identifier"]').val(test);
}):
</script>
```

Answer (score 16):

To convert to lowercase :

```
var lowercase = 'This Is A Sample'.toLowerCase();
```

To Replace empty space:

```
var Replace= 'This Is A Sample'.replace(/ /g,"-");
```

take a look at this example

[@JSbin](http://jsbin.com/urebi4/2/edit)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var el = document.getElementById('identifier');
var text = el.value;
el.value = text.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-');
</script>
```

or if you are using JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('identifier').value = $('identifier').value.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-');
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var lower = $('input#textFieldId').val().toLowerCase(); // to lower case
var hyp = lower.replace(/ /g,"-");                      // spaces to hyphens
$('input#hiddenFieldId').val(hyp);                      // in hidden field
```

[Check](http://jsfiddle.net/LT6Aq/)

Answer (score 1):

To switch your text to lowercase, use the JavaScript [toLowerCase() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toLowerCase.asp).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var str="Hello World!";
document.write(str.toLowerCase());

</script>
```

See [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657433/replace-space-with-dash-javascript) on how to replace all the spaces with dashes using JavaScript.