# As user types populate different textbox

Tags: jquery

I have this code to populate two textboxes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tb1').keyup(function(){
        var content = $('.tb1').val();
        $('.tb2').val(content);
    });
});
```

However, the only other thing I'd like to do is if the user enters a `space` I'd like to populate that with a `-`.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [replace space with dash javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657433/replace-space-with-dash-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method:

```
$('.tb2').val(content.replace(/\s/g, '-'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.tb1').keyup(function(){
         var content = $('.tb1').val();
         var newContent=content.replace(' ','-');
        $('.tb2').val(newContent);
    });
    });
```

Comment: `content.replace(' ','-')` will only replace the first occurrence. You need the `g`lobal flag.