# Regex to replace space with dash in jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

I have the following code, which populates a field upon typing into another...

```
$('#title').bind('keyup keypress blur', function() 
{  

    var myStr = $(this).val()
        myStr=myStr.toLowerCase();
        myStr=myStr.replace(/ /g,"-");
        myStr=myStr.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.]+/g,"");
        myStr=myStr.replace(/\.+/g, "-");


    $('#filename').val(myStr); 
});
```

The code works to remove any none alphanumeric characters, however I want it to replace spaces with a '-' dash.

If i change the dash to a period '.' this works, not sure why or how to remedy it? Regex confuses me.

[**JSFIDDLE here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2a4gx/)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

***UPDATE***

Just got it to work as required using this...

```
<script>
$('#title').bind('keyup keypress blur', function() 
{  

    var myStr = $(this).val()
        myStr=myStr.toLowerCase();
        myStr=myStr.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+/g,"");
        myStr=myStr.replace(/\s+/g, "-");


    $('#filename').val(myStr); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [replace space with dash javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657433/replace-space-with-dash-javascript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend using this regex instead of the first one you have `/(^\s+|[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+|\s+$)/g`. It will prevent dashes from being added in the beginning and the end of the string, just in case the user accidentally adds spaces there.

```
$('#title').bind('keyup keypress blur', function() 
{  

    var myStr = $(this).val()
    myStr=myStr.toLowerCase();
    myStr=myStr.replace(/(^\s+|[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+|\s+$)/g,"");   //this one
    myStr=myStr.replace(/\s+/g, "-");


    $('#filename').val(myStr); 
});
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/imtheman/drUN9/1/)

Answer (score 9):

`\s` means `whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")` in regex:

```
myStr=myStr.replace(/\s+/g, "-");
```

Comment: That's not entirely accurate, `\s` means whitespace. That includes things like tab and newline as well. Only space would be just `/ /`.

Comment: Please edit your answer to correct your first sentence. As pointed out by @DaniëlKnippers you are currently giving misleading information

Answer (score 3):

You're undoing your own work with this:

```
myStr=myStr.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.]+/g,""); //removes dashes (-)
```

Change it to this:

```
myStr=myStr.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+/g,"");
```

You say to delete anything that isn't a letter, number or `.` (therefore removing dashes)

Just adding a dash/hyphen into the character group sorts it out